# Searching Excel sheet for errors

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Imagine a huge worksheet with tens of thousands of formulas.  I want to be able to quickly find all the errors to correct them.  I have found that using the normal search procedure I can type in things like #DIV/0! or #NAME? and it will find them, but I would have to type in all the various types of errors separately and that is somewhat time consuming.

Is there a way to simply search for any error?

One solution we seem to use at work is to put most formulas inside =if(iserror()) or now =iferror() and to just have it output "error" if it is an error.  Is this necessary?  Or, is there a way to find all the errors without it?

Comment: You may consider asking this on Stack Overflow instead if you want to se programming (VBA) solutions as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel's `Go To` tool will help here.  Press `F5` and select `Special...` then click `Formulas` and check only `Errors`.  This will highlight every cell with an error result.

From that point, hit Enter to move between them or highlight them with a color, etc.

Comment: It looks like it's tab to go between them, not enter.  Other than that, this seems like what I was looking for!  Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped.  Interestingly though, both Enter and Tab work for me in Excel 2007.